# Saving data to an existing entity with Kinvey

Tags: ios, swift, kinvey

I am using Kinvey as a backend on my app and I need to know how to modify an object. Whenever I pull the object and modify the object it creates a new object in the server. I need it to modify the existing object. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is update the object and set the entityID to the id you update and save it like you are saving a new object.